# text color not changing with css

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, buddypress

I am working on a wordpress / buddypress site. In the groups page, I have changed the page title background color. However, over the page title background is the element that shows how many groups there are and it is in the same color. I am trying to change the text color to white but it is not changing. the code for this is:

```
<div id="item-statistics" class="follows">
            <h1 class="main-title">Groups &amp; Clubs</h1>

            <span class="create-a-group"><a href="https://www.villagemixer.com/groups/create/" class="group-create no-ajax">Create a Group</a></span>

            <div class="numbers">
                <span>
                    <p>25</p>
                    <p>Groups</p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I was able to change the page title with

```
.main-title {
color: white;
}
```

however, the class showing the numbers (25) and groups (Groups) will not change when using its class selector like this

```
.numbers {
color: white;
}
```

Using the same class selector, I am able to change the background color though. Any thoughts?

Comment: be more specific and target `p` also ... and if it's not enough use `!important`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there's some other CSS conflicting the same

Try adding `!important`

```
.numbers{
   color:white !important;
}
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the P color:

```
.numbers span p {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I just updated it with your suggestion. It is still not changing.

Comment: OK. So I just used your suggestion but added !important and it works! Thanks!